# How to dynamically modify subquery SQL in Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Suppose I have two Access queries `getData_join` and `getData_static`:

`getData_static`:

```
select * from someTable where someTable.property="value"
```

`getData_join`:

```
select * from someTable inner join otherTable on someTable.property=otherTable.property
```

The database has a lot of queries that call `getData_join`, e.g., `items_getData`:

```
select * from items inner join getData_join on items.property=getData_join.property
```

I want to set up a switch in the front end that will let the user select whether these queries call `getData_static` or `getData_join`.  Rather than make two separate sets of queries, I was thinking about maybe having a generic `getData` query with a dummy clause like:

```
select * from someTable [insertClause]
```

and then defining the SQL on the fly using a QueryDef, like so:

```
Function modify_getData(isJoin As Boolean) As QueryDef

Dim qdf As QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("getData")

If isJoin Then
    qdf.sql = Replace(qdf.sql, "[insertClause]", "inner join otherTable on someTable.property=otherTable.property")
Else
    qdf.sql = Replace(qdf.sql, "[insertClause]", "where someTable.property=""value""")
End If

Set modify_getData = qdf

End Function
```

The problem is that the front end doesn't call `getData` directly, it calls `items_getData`, so creating a modified `getData` QueryDef wouldn't be of use here.  Is there a way to dynamically modify the SQL of a subquery in Access so that the modified SQL will get used by another query that calls it?

Comment: Why not keep as two separate queries especially since many other queries even forms/reports use them? Your code could break and any object using query will fail. Queries are non-data application items so do not take up too much space. Plus Access's engine compiles and optimizes saved queries rather than VBA scripted queries.

Comment: @Parfait: I think the issue is maintenance of all those queries, not space.

Comment: Your replace would work only once, because afterwards there would be no more `[insertClause]` in the qdf.sql.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to replace the query name in all queries, this can be easily done with a loop over `Db.QueryDefs`.

I would have a reference query with only `SELECT * FROM getData_static`.

Read its `.Sql` to determine the current state of the queries. If it doesn't match the "switch", run

```vb
Set Db = CurrentDb
For Each qdf in Db.QueryDefs
    qdf.Sql = Replace(qdf.Sql, "getData_static", "getData_join")
Next qdf
```

or vice versa.

You have to be sure that "getData_static" and "getData_join" are unique enough that they will never appear as part of another string in any of your queries.